# Websites for push message sending with p8 file

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, p8

I am using push notification with **.p8** file in ios app. i know dummy apn sender with .pem or .p12 file. can anyone suggest some push notification sender website like [this website](https://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/) that accept p8 file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Testing the Push Notification Online using the .p8 Certificate/File. You can go to this Website [APNS Checker for .p8 File](https://www.logisticinfotech.com/send-push-notification-online/)

For doing this,

1. You need to Upload your .p8 File
2. Enter Key-Id and Team-Id
3. Enter Bundle Id
4. Enter Device Token's or a Single Token
5. Check **isProduction** if needed (For me it worked after enabling isProduction)
6. Finally Enter the required Message and click on **Send Push**

Comment: Hope it helped You @dineshsharma

Comment: It is not working, infinity loading when you fill all details and clicks on send push notification action button